# Computer turns on, and screen says no input, yet works with other computers

Tags: desktop-computer, hp-pavilion

Old computer, working for years.  Now the power light goes on, the HD whirls, but there does not seem to be any video output.  The screen says no input, and the screen and cable have been tested with other machines.

The model is Hp Pavilion Slimline S3720f

Does it need a new motherboard because of viedo failure, or is there another issue it could be having?

Comment: Does a different screen work with the computer?

Comment: Could be power supply. Gives the look of power on, CPU fan spins and case lights turn on, but no boot. Had a new 900 watter that drove me nuts because I had ruled it out due to being new, but IT was the issue.

Comment: Broken video card? Video card overheats? Video card not firmly set into the motherboard? Broken video cord? Broken connector (happened a _long_ time ago that a card got a pin bent)? My office screen just refuses to work if the (supposedly symmetrical) cable is oriented the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last thing you have to try is to connect the computer to another monitor/TV or using a different video output. If the problem doesn't solve, it means that the video output of the computer got damaged. You can also try to access the computer BIOS (you need to read the manual or HP knowledgebase to see how to do this). If you don't see anything on the screen, then it is definitely an internal problem.

Comment: there is only one video output.  If its the video output on the motherboard is this fixable, or needs a new motherboard?

Comment: It depends on which component got damaged, but basically a new video card is required. Referring to the specifications, your computer has a PCI-E slot available for an external graphics card, so there is no need for replacing the motherboard. But the problem could also be related to other components. Does your computer beep when it starts? Did it use to beep?

Comment: external video card - that would be the idea I was looking for.  Not sure there was a beep before.  Whats that to show?  the computer is booting fine, or not?  If the power comes on but there is no beep where there used to be what does that show?

Comment: I probably used the wrong word. By external I mean not onboard. As for the beep: computers often include a speaker that is connected to the motherboard and it is used by the BIOS to report the result of the power-on self test. A single, short beep means everything is ok. Other beep codes are used to report problems with memory, cpu or other things. Nowadays most of the computers come without a system speaker, so you are not able to hear the beeps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a Offboard videocard?

Try removing your memory modules, and check if the motherboard make the 3 beeps (obviously check if your motherboard has the speaker for the beeps, if it doesnt, find one and plug on it)

A memory or CPU with a failure is very uncommon, and your HD wont interfere on the main boot... Try removing the motherboard BIOS battery for a few minutes and put it back, remember to disconnect the power cable on this step..

If it have a Offobard VGA, remove it, and remove all the other offboard cards, and try to power on...

One question... Did you check the powersupply voltage selector? Here in brazil is 220v, sometimes we forgot the PSU on 120v, it powers on but doesnt work..

Comment: To avoid a misconception I'd use the word 'discrete' instead of offboard. That makes it sound like you're talking about a Razer Core or similar.